# How to develop a metro template using bootstrap framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to develop a metro template using Bootstrap framework. I cant get any proper reference link or tutorial. I hope its possible to design a metro template using bootstrap framework.if so send me some reference link.

Comment: Have you tried [Metro UI CSS Bootstrap](http://metroui.org.ua/)?

Comment: +1 KyleMit. Good Observation :)

Answer (score 5):

You can try these links.

http://metroui.org.ua/

http://bootswatch.com/ and go Cosmo or Yeti themes

http://aozora.github.io/bootmetro/

http://talkslab.com/metro-bootstrap/index.html

http://www.jquery4u.com/bootstraps/metro-bootstraps/

Answer (score 2):

there are many templates using bootstrap with the metro style.

https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/metro-mania-no.1-metro-bootstrap-theme-WB07F9G8L

take a look this link: http://www.jquery4u.com/bootstraps/metro-bootstraps/

Comment: talkslab link is dead

Answer (score 1):

Metro UI Bootstrap Based. It's better to reuse the stuff, rather than building a new one.

[Click Here](http://metroui.org.ua/)

[image]

Comment: I could not find where this is Bootstrap anymore.

Comment: While this one is the best one I have seen. It is infact not a bootstrap template, although it is labeled similarly and is based on it.